# H2 Parsedatetime yyyyMMddhhmmss

Tags: database, h2

I need to parse a date like the following 20140101120000 which is yyyyMMddhhmmss to the H2 timestamp format of yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss and I can't seem to figure out how to make it work. Here is what I am trying.

```
parseDateTime('20140101000000','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

I am getting this error

```
Error parsing "20140101120000"
```

I am reading this date in from a CSV that would be very inefficient to change. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
parseDateTime('20140101000000','yyyyMMddHHmmss')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked. I am still having an issue with formatting the date when reading from the CSV but I feel like that would be another question so I will make a new post.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to parse this value, because function don't understand it. You can parse '2014-01-01 00:00:00' into array, but i think not value like yours. I recommend you to use substr function to parse your value.

$date = '20140101120000';
$yyyy = substr($date,0,4);
$mm   = substr($date,4,2);
$dd   = substr($date,6,2);
$hours   = substr($date,8,2);
$min   = substr($date,10,2);
$sec   = substr($date,12,2);
$newdate = "{$yyyy}-{$mm}-{$dd}  {$hours}:{$min}.{$sec}";